# Need to undo group policy changes from the recovery console

Tags: windows-7, drivers, group-policy

I seem to have gotten myself into a major pickle. I have a lenovo w520 laptop and I tried to attach a keyboard. The keyboard wasn't being recognised properly. I removed all the keyboards from the device manager list and rebooted. At the login screen the USB keyboard worked fine, but after logging in, windows automatically seemed to install a ps/2 keyboard. I thought this was a mistake on windows part because it mis identified the USB keyboard. I now realise that it was probably installing the drivers for the onboard keyboard.

To prevent this automatic driver installation, I enabled the "Prevent Installation of Devices not described by other policy settings" group policy setting as described [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-automatic-driver-installation-in-windows-vista/)

Now, after reboot at the login screen, windows doesn't recognise my laptop keyboard or mouse or the external keyboard. I am completely locked out of my system. I can alternate boot and get to a system recovery screen and use my keyboard and mouse. I can now get to a recovery console, but I don't know how I can undo the group policy setting from the command line.

Any other suggestions on how I can regain the keyboard and mouse without having to reinstall Windows?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of future Netizens. I tried to find the supposed registry keys specified [here](http://www.group-policy.com/ref/policy/185/Prevent_installation_of_devices_not_described_by_other_policy_settings). They didn't exist. I tried creating the appropriate registry key structure and setting the value. It didn't make any difference either. The registry settings [here](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/plug-and-prey-malicious-usb-devices#_Prevent_installation_of_3) don't exist either. In the end I gave up and reinstalled windows.